# How to configure a router for two subnets?

Tags: router, subnet, hub

I'm basically trying to configure a router to act as both a hub and a router.

I have two routers in my network, one with the IP 192.168.2.1 (Router A), which acts as a DHCP server, as well as several clients, one of them is another router with the IP 192.168.2.10 (Router B).

Router A is connected to Router B through the WAN port in order to obtain two separate networks. Router B has the DHCP disabled, and a local IP 192.168.1.1 with several clients attached to it with an IP 192.168.1.0/24. None of those clients can be reached from the other network as intended. However, I do have one client attached to Router B, that needs to be part of the other network.

How do I now connect that client with an IP 192.168.**2**.2 to Network A through Router B, without assigning a local IP and port forwarding. This only works, if I use Router B as a hub by connecting Router A to one of the LAN ports on Router B, instead of using the WAN port, but that creates only one network. How do I configure Router B (Cisco RVS4000) to have a client with an IP to which Router B is connected to.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `None of those clients can be reached from the other network as intended.` Note that this is not necessarily the effect you get by having two networks / broadcast domains. It really just depends on the routes configured and the firewall on the router. While in *some* cases the NAT'ing might break things, it is NOT a sure thing. If there's no corresponding firewall filtering and *stateless* NAT that breaks such communication, all you need to have is a route for the specific 192.168.1.x on 192.168.2.2, with 192.168.2.10 as the gateway / nexthop of the route.

Comment: Do you have a reason to make it so difficult?  For a simple network where you need to exchange information between devices, just use one subnet.  Simple to set up

Comment: @Tom Yan You are right. I'm entirely aware that this might not always be the case, however in my case, I would hope it is, since I'm using a firewall that in theory should keep both networks separated. But I'm glad you've pointed that out, also for other users who might not be aware of that.

Comment: @John I do, for different reasons, both security and hardware wise, otherwise it would have been easy to realize, as you mentioned by having them on the same subnet. I could also get a hub/switch between both routers and connect client 192.168.2.2 to it, which would also solve that issue. But, the infrastructure doesn't really allow that, and I have to keep certain devices in a local network (B), separated from the other network (A), which is also accessible from outside.

Comment: If you have gear that permits it, VLAN's might work better.  More complicated, and I have only dabbled, but VLAN's help with security and (where needed) connectivity.